# Creating list inside the Activity after clicking RecyclerView

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

As the title says, I want to create a new list inside the Activity after clicking the `RecyclerView`. I am using `JSON` to get the data and the data inside apparently has a list for name, comments, and date time. I can set them into a `TextView` but that's not what I wanted. I need to show them as a list. The list should have name, comments, and date time. Thanks!

Comment: You need json parsing and display them to the RecyclerView.

Comment: I already bind the data, using the adapter and show it to recyclerview. i can retrieve the value by using get and show it to a view but the data will append next to each other. so i want to create a list for that

Comment: Show your code here.

Comment: You need to use the custom adapter with your desired layout.

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: please provide your json format :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Custom Adapter instead of the `ArrayAdapter`. So that you can customize the view how ever you want.

For example in your case

row_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <!-- Name -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Marshmallow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <!-- Comments-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Android 6.0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    <!-- Date and Time-->

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateandtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="11th August"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

DataModel.java

```
public class DataModel {

    String name;
    String comment,
    String date;


    public DataModel(String name, String type, String comment, String date) {
        this.name=name;
        this.comment=comment;
        this.date=date;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

}
```

And finally your Custom Adapter should be like below

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtComment;
        TextView txtDate;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext=context;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       // your on click code
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            viewHolder.txtComment = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
            viewHolder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateandtime);


            result=convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result=convertView;
        }


        viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getName());
        viewHolder.txtComment.setText(dataModel.getComment());
        viewHolder.txtDate.setText(dataModel.getDate());
        viewHolder.info.setOnClickListener(this);
        viewHolder.info.setTag(position);
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

You have to set the adapter like this.

```
ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels; // then add your data into it

CustomAdapter  adapter= new CustomAdapter(dataModels,getApplicationContext());

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Check this [example](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) for better idea.